# Highlight cells for which the value equals a value in a list when another column in the list equals TRUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have names in column `A` and `B` repeating several times in both columns. Column `D` contains the unique names without duplicates. So I used column `D` to calculate the number of times a name has occurred in column `A` and `B`, which is in column `E` and `F` respectively. If names in `A` and `B` are equal I should get a `TRUE`.

What I am trying to do now is to highlight any name (as the arrows shows in the pic) in column `A` that has the TRUE value in `G` for the name in column `D`.

[image: see image here]

Comment: You should try conditional formatting...

Comment: I am aware of conditional formatting, but I can't seem to get the exact formula for this.

Comment: Then show us the exact formula you are trying. Use screenshots of the conditional formatting windows if you have to

Comment: In a conditional format for C2.  `=Index(G:G, Match($C2, D:D))="TRUE"`

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options:

A) either **hard-code** it manually for the case there are not too many names...

[image]

B) or add helper columns. An approach could be to count the count the occurences (e.g., with `=AND(COUNTIF($A:$A;"="&$A2)=1;COUNTIF($C:$C;"="&$A2)=1)` in B2) and then format based on the helper column (formula like `=$B2=TRUE`).

[image]